# Android remove notifcation by code

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

As the title say I would like to remove the notification by code, but I can't get it to work. I am trying to use the method cancelAll();
What's happening is that the notification get removed for like a mili second and it's back. It is kind of confusing. Anyone know how to solve the issue?

Best regards HFHerasen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each notification has a unique ID, you can cancel your notification by it's own ID's.

```
public void killNotificationBar(Context c, int id)
{
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) c.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.cancel(id);
}
```

Comment: Thank's for answer!
I have tryed to use that method aswell, but even if I reference to the exact id or cancelAll() method the same thing is happening.

Comment: Never mind!I found out that I had done something wrong in my code.. So your method works great:) but now the cancelAll() also works hehe. Ill mark your answer as right.